# How do I read a .txt file from a different directory in python?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to read clients.txt from a different directory. I have a clients.txt saved on a desktop folder called "flaskpractice"
and the path is (C:\Desktop\flaskpractice), how can I read that file that is located in a different path?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    with open('clients.txt') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)

    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: open file using `f = open('path-to-file','r')`

Comment: If the answer works then you have to accept the answer by pressing the tick button.

Comment: Hey you removed me answer from accepted. Why do you click accept then unaccept and repeat like that? When you have accept then you should not unaccept again. Please accept it again 

Comment: Hey you haven't accepted the answer still

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give the absolute file path.

```
with open('C:/users/user/desktop/flaskpractice/clients.txt') as json_file:
```

The above code is just an example you have to replace the file path with the real absolute file path on your computer.